# How many times is (+ 1) computed here?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, ghc

On my functional programming exam, I had the following question:

How many times is (+ 1) function computed in the following code?

```
(map (+ 1) [1 .. 10]) !! 5
```

where the index function is defined like this:

```
(h:_) !! 0 = h
(_:t) !! x = t !! (x-1)
```

I would say 6 times, but the correct answer seems to be 1, and I cannot understand why. I could not find a good enough explanation of lazy evaluation in Haskell, so I would like to know what is the correct answer and why. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Only once. Since `(+1)` on the other elements are postponed.

Comment: Note that the definition of `map` is also necessary to properly answer this question. (Willem's answer makes the reasonable assumption that `map` is defined in a similar way to that [in the Report Prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1720009.1) or [in GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map).)

Comment: Well technically since there is never a demand to match, print, or branch on the result of the given statement, the statement it's self would never be evaluated. There is an argument to be made that 0 is the correct answer.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller: well I assume that they typically include evaluation of the final value (as if one would write an implicit `print` or something).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> many times is `(+ 1)` function computed in the following code?

It is calculated only *once*. `map` does not force to calculate `f xi` on the elements in the result list. These calculations are postponed (just like everything else in Haskell), only when we need to calculate the value of a specific item, we do that.

`map` is specified in [chapter 9 of the Haskell'10 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1720009.1) as:

> ```
> -- Map and append  
> map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
> map f []     = []  
> map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
> ```

There are no `seq`, bang patterns, etc. here to force evaluation of `f x`, so the `map` function will indeed "yield" an `f x`, but *without* evaluating `f x`, it is postponed until it is necessary (and it might happen that we are not interested in some of these values, and thus can save some CPU cycles).

We can take a look how Haskell will evaluate this:

```
   (!!) (map (+ 1) [1 .. 10]) 5
-> (!!) ((+1) 1 : map (+1) [2..10]) 5
-> (!!) (map (+1) [2..10]) 4
-> (!!) ((+1) 1 : map (+1) [3..10]) 4
-> (!!) (map (+1) [3..10]) 3
-> (!!) ((+1) 1 : map (+1) [4..10]) 3
-> (!!) (map (+1) [4..10]) 2
-> (!!) ((+1) 1 : map (+1) [5..10]) 2
-> (!!) (map (+1) [5..10]) 1
-> (!!) ((+1) 1 : map (+1) [6..10]) 1
-> (!!) (map (+1) [6..10]) 0
-> (!!) ((+1) 6 : map (+1) [7..10]) 0
-> (+1) 6
-> 7
```

This is because `map f [x1, x2, ..., xn]` eventually maps to a list `[f x1, f x2, ..., f xn]`, but it does *not* compute `f xi` of the elements, that computation is postponed until we actually would need the value in that list, and do something with it (like priting it).

This can result in a significant performance boost, given `f` is an expensive function, and we only need the value of a small amount of elements in the list.

Comment: thank you! is it some tool that prints the evaluation like this or did you just write it?

Comment: @VladIordache: I once stumbled upon a website that could show the lazy evaluation, but I can not find it immediately.

Answer (score 7):

Let's test it by doing something horrible. You'll need to import the `Debug.Trace` module for this.

```
ghci> (map (\x -> trace "Performing..." (x + 1)) [1..10]) !! 5
```

Now, we'll get that totally safe `IO` action to happen every time the lambda expression is called. When we run this in GHCi, we get

```
Performing
7
```

So only once.

As a sanity check, we could remove the `!! 5` bit.

```
ghci> map (\x -> trace "Performing..." (x + 1)) [1..10]
[Performing
2,Performing
3,Performing
4,Performing
5,Performing
6,Performing
7,Performing
8,Performing
9,Performing
10,Performing
11]
```

So it's definitely happening 10 times when we ask for the whole list.